# Adding dependency property to custom control causes strange errors to occur to style

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to create a custom control which extends from a ListBoxItem as shown here:

```
public class MainNavListBoxItem : ListBoxItem
{
    public MainNavListBoxItem()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MainNavListBoxItem);
    }
}
```

I have a style on it that is defined in a ResourceDictionary as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="assets:MainNavListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="assets:MainNavListBoxItem">
                    <Grid Height="50">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
...
```

Now it compiles and runs fine like this, but as soon as I add an extra dependency property to the `MainNavListBoxItem` class, i start getting errors like this:

> Failed to create a 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty' from the text 'Padding'.

If I re-arrange the Setter tags within the style, it will always report the top-most one.

And my dependency property code for reference:

```
public ImageSource ImageDark
{
    get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageDarkProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImageDarkProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageDarkProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ImageDark", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MainNavListBoxItem), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

What is going on here?! I want to be able to use this ImageDark dependency property from within the style!

I have done a lot of searching on this error but nothing seems to be relevant to this problem.

Comment: Not sure this is relevant without testing, but the way you specify your default style key is abnormal. You should override the metadata in a static constructor. It could be confusing WPF doing it in your instance constructor. See, for example, [here](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html).

Comment: you cant override the metadata in silverlight, can you?

Comment: Sorry, thought this was WPF.

Comment: Your PropertyMetadata specifies a default of zero for an ImageSource??

Comment: That was the issue.. Hadn't even noticed that I didn't change it to 'null'. Post as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was because I forgot to change `new PropertyMetadata(0)` in my dependency property to `new PropertyMetadata(null)`. Thanks Kent.